# How to get %CPU and %MEM only from top command

Tags: linux, command, top-command

I am looking for the command/filter for the top command to get only %CPU and %MEM columns.
Currently I am using like :

Command:
top -b -p 1665,2398 -n 1 -o -PID | tail -n +7

Output:

PID USER    PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM   TIME+ COMMAND

1665 user   20   0   40.4g   2.3g  39956 S   0.0  2.6   0:26.67 java

2398 user   20   0 5630552 271860  17552 S   0.0  0.3   0:04.33 java

Expected output:

PID  %CPU %MEM
1665 0.0  2.6
2398 0.0  0.3

Please give some idea. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try with Awk.
`top -b -p 4225,5290 -n 1 |grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%-8s  %-8s  %-8s\n", $1, $9, $10); }'`

PID       %CPU      %MEM

4225      43.8      2.1

5290      0.0       2.1

Comment: good . please accept it as solution to mark it answered

Answer (score 2):

I think the following may be sufficient:

```
top -b -p 1665,2398 -n 1 -o -PID | tail -n +7 | awk '{print $1,$9,$10}'
```